# How to design a game with "lanes"?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to create a lane system for my game but I am having a little bit of trouble doing this. I am trying to make it so I can have 5 lanes and I have an abstract Ship class that has a moveTo method and I want to be able to move between lanes but I am having to problems creating the lanes and moving the Ship to the specified lane here is my current code.

This is my abstract ship class: notice the MoveTo(int laneNumber) method

```
package me.heirteir.Amazed.gameObjects;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public abstract class Ship {
    public static final int PLAYER = 0;

    public abstract void render(float delta);

    public abstract void moveTo(int laneNumber);

    public abstract void setTexture(Texture texture);

    public abstract Texture getTexture();

    public abstract Vector2 getPos();

    public abstract Rectangle getRect();

    public abstract int getType();
}
```

and I don't really have much of an idea for creating a global lane system but this is my progress

```
package me.heirteir.Amazed.gameObjects.framework;

public class Lanes {
    public static final int LANES_AMOUNT = 5;
    float lane1, lane2, lane3, lane4, lane5;
    public Lanes(float width, float height){

    }
}
```

So overall I am trying to create a 5 lane system with a ship that can move to random lanes how would I go about achieving this thanks for reading!

Comment: This is not something to be asked on Stack Overflow. We're here to help with specific problems you're facing, not for structural or architectural advice that is completely subjective.

Comment: The lanes should be an *abstract* concept, ie. `public int laneNumber` (or a specific Lane object if preferred) as part of each Ship, or inverted such that each Ship "belongs to" a Lane. I believe the current *conceptual* issue is making the Lanes a composite object from the start instead of having n Lane objects/instances. The rendering is only a secondary concern, although a ship should probably only be rendered at a "lane y" +/- "local ship y" (such that the sprite is drawn within a particular set of bounds). Anyway, this isn't a "bad" question but it definitely feels Broad.

Comment: Here I will get more strict with what I am asking basically I have no idea how to setup a lane system once I know how to make a lane system I can easily move the ship from 1 lane to another basically how would I spread 5 lanes across the screen evenly while having the screen's width

Comment: Create a Lane (not Lanes) class. Create 5 Lane objects and save these in a Lanes array (such that indices 0..4 correspond to each Lane). Assign each Lane object a particular x/y axis, using math to divvy up the game coordinates. Each Lane can be found by looking at the corresponding index in the Lanes array.

Comment: Thank you this clears up what I am trying to do!

Comment: @AlbertoGomez I'm not sure how LibGDX works, but if it has a concept of "groups" (such that sprites belong to a particular group) it might make sense to also have a Lane represent ("contain") a particular group object as well. Then moving an object between Lanes would also mean moving it between groups (where each Lane contains a separate group).

Comment: I fixed the problem and cleared it up below for anyone in the future thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I designed a solution from the comments I created a Lanes class that I could use to access the array of Lanes then I did a little math and came up with this solution

```
package me.heirteir.Amazed.gameObjects.framework;

import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class Lanes {
    public static final int LANE_COUNT = 5;
    public static Array<Lane> lanes = new Array<Lane>();

    public static void setupLanes(float width, float height) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        lanes.add(new Lane(width / LANE_COUNT, height, width / LANE_COUNT * x + 1, height));
    }
   }
}
```

Then here is my actual lane class
    package me.heirteir.Amazed.gameObjects.framework;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Lane {
    private Vector2 pos;
    private Rectangle rect;

    public Lane(float width, float height, float x, float y) {
    rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.width = width;
    rect.height = height;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;

    pos = new Vector2(x, y);
    }

    public Vector2 getPos(){
    return pos;
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
    return rect;
    }
}
```

then this is where I render just to make sure the lanes were created correctly

```
    public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    game.batch.begin();

    for (Lane lane : Lanes.lanes) {
        game.batch.draw(game.texture, lane.getPos().x, 0, lane.getRect().width,     lane.getRect().getHeight());
}

game.batch.end();
}
```

This was the final result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyX1h.jpg